# jpeg binary file header with inverted width & height

Tags: node.js, binary, format, jpeg

I am calculating a jpg file size by parsing it as a binary file with nodejs. 
But the computed width height gives 4032x3024 when the actual size is 3024x4032.
Its header 0xFFC0 block is as follow:
ffc0 0011 080b d00f c003

According to JPEG format, sizes should be : 
height = 0bd0 (i.e:3024)
width = 0fc0 (i.e:4032)

(Using Imagemagick identify program confirms this calculation:
identify HJ7XFd9le.jpg
HJ7XFd9le.jpg JPEG 4032x3024 4032x3024+0+0 8-bit sRGB 380KB 0.000u 0:00.000)

But when viewing the image in my mac viewer, the inspector indicates a size of 3024x 4032!

How can i compute the correct size programmatically by parsing the file as a binary file?

Thanks!

Comment: The JPEG SOF0 (start of frame) marker encodes the image height followed by the image width. ImageMagick Identify is showing the correct size.

Comment: It is the correct size for most of the jpeg files. But i've received on my server some jpeg files taken with an iphone 6 where the width and height are inverted in the SOF0 block. I was wondering if there was another way to get the size of the file (mac viewer inspector, gives the correct size in the general tab, but the inverted size in the exif tab).

Comment: Ah - it's not that the size is inverted, it's that you need to respect the EXIF orientation (rotated 90/270). The sensor is in a certain orientation and if you capture the image rotated, the camera software may signify the change by putting a non-0 orientation in the APP1 EXIF data.

Comment: @BitBank thanks a lot i've been scratching my head for days on this! I've been looking at the exif specifications to see how to read the rotation tag. The structure seems quite dense. Is there a simple way to get the rotation tag?

Comment: Found this interesting site describing exif structure: https://www.codeproject.com/kb/graphics/exiflibrary.aspx

Comment: Simple is in the eye of the beholder ;) I find it pretty easy to access. The EXIF data in the APP1 marker is organized like a TIFF file header and tag 274 has the info. See here: http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html

Comment: @BitBank: thanks, really,  for the great pointers!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ah - it's not that the size is inverted, it's that you need to respect the EXIF orientation (rotated 90/270). The sensor is in a certain orientation and if you capture the image rotated, the camera software may signify the change by putting a non-0 orientation in the APP1 EXIF data. – **BitBank**